# Por que não criar uma barra de pesquisa para respostas dadas pelo usuário?

Tags: novo-recurso, pesquisa

Há algum tempo atrás eu abri uma questão de um usuário sobre um assunto que eu já tinha respondido em outra pergunta. Então eu abri a aba de **respostas** do meu perfil para procurar por essa resposta e marcar a questão como duplicada, mas acabei levando muito tempo até acha-la.

Então eu pensei, por que não criar uma barra de pesquisa no campo de respostas do usuário?

Alguns aí podem achar que isso seria inútil já que o usuário pode pesquisar na barra de pesquisa principal do site. Mas vamos pensar que a pergunta seja algo como `"Como criar uma variável?"` (é uma pergunta bem genérica mesmo só para dar um exemplo).

Se colocarmos isso como pesquisa encontraremos muitos resultados, mas se houvesse uma barra de pesquisa própria para as respostas de cada usuário, seria possível reduzir as buscas.

Pense por exemplo que você quer editar uma resposta antiga sua. Se você tiver dado mais de 2000 respostas aqui no site, certamente vai levar um bom tempo até encontrar a questão certa.

Comment: Acho que não o farão porque é possível fazer isso na barra de pesquisa: `user:157404 Como criar uma variável`. Basicamente o conceito é o mesmo, se entendi a sugestão

Comment: Se quiser ser mais específico: `user:157404 is:answer title:Como criar uma variável`. Veja todas as opções em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching

Comment: Eu acho chato as pessoas marcarem respostas como dup das proprias, mas não procurarem respostas de outros que existem inclusive em perguntas mais antigas, tem muita gente que responde pergunta boba com algo "bom" (não otimo), sendo que já existe perguntas com respostas as vezes mais completas ou que cobririam suficientemente o assunto, mas não o fazem e quando fazem é em mérito proprio, indicando suas proprias outras respostas. A busca deveria ser pelo conteúdo e não pela pessoa e se for pra responder melhor porque não responder na pergunta existente mais antiga?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu não estou falando sobre escolher a resposta própria para indicar dentre outras respostas melhores, mas sim sobre respostas para perguntas que podem ser parecidas com outras perguntas porém tendo um assunto diferente ou então respostas únicas sobre o assunto. Por exemplo, eu tenho aqui algumas respostas para questões de exercícios de faculdade. Só que esse exercício X pode ser parecido com uma questão Y ou Z mesmo tendo um assunto diferente. Dessa forma dificultaria encontrar a questão certa com minha resposta para indicar ao usuário na barra de pesquisa principal.

Comment: O hkotsubo já me disse aí em cima sobre como filtrar as pesquisas por usuário para achar a questão com mais facilidade, no entanto ainda acho que pode ser uma boa ideia criar uma barra de pesquisa própria para isso. Ficaria mais fácil fazer pesquisas na minha opinião e seria visualmente mais agradável no site. Fora que podem existir pessoas que não conheçam essa forma de filtragem como eu que não sabia há algumas horas atrás.

Comment: Pode não estar falando, mas aproveito o espaço para falar o que é bastante comum na comunidade, e não estou falando de ti, mas simplesmente da ideia empregada aqui, se é pra pesquisar algo pra fechar como dup pesquise pelo conteúdo e não pelas pessoas, pq as ALGUMAS pessoas vão vir ler a sua pergunta aqui no META e vão entender q o ideal é o egocentrismo delas ;) ... Reforço a todos que lerem: antes de responder procurem se já não existe resposta no site que cubra o assunto.

Comment: Ok mas mudando de assunto. O que acha da ideia de criar essa barra de pesquisa para as abas de respostas, perguntas e favoritos para facilitar a vida das pessoas ? Ficaria mais fácil de pesquisar e ficaria visualmente mais bonito também para o site.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 acho que parece útil pra ti, mas não é de fato interessante pra maioria e nem para o propósito de se focar no conteudo, já temos sistema de favoritos e o buscador tem um esquema de "palavras chaves" para você mesmo criar uma filtragem, você pode acompanhar feeds de perguntas e agora é possivel clicar em SEGUIR abaixo da pergunta ou resposta, algo que é novo no site, com isto você será notificado de qualquer alteração.

Comment: Isso é verdade, vejo pessoas aqui marcando como duplicadas apontando para as próprias respostas, é a corrida desenfreada por pontos e medalhas

Answer (score 5):

## Não acho que é necessário criar outra barra de pesquisa só para isso

A barra de pesquisa atual já possui essa opção (além de muitas outras). Se quer buscar as suas respostas basta colocar:

```
user:me is:answer texto da resposta
```

Ou ainda:

```
user:me is:answer body:"texto exato da resposta"
```

O texto entre aspas buscará pela frase exata, enquanto sem aspas buscará respostas que contém qualquer uma das palavras indicadas. Eu acho até que o `body:` neste caso é redundante, pois respostas só possuem `body` e não `title` (veja mais abaixo detalhes sobre a busca por `title`).

Lembrando que o `user:me` pode ser trocado por `user:1234` (onde "1234" é o ID do usuário, que você pode descobrir clicando no perfil do mesmo - o ID aparecerá no link, algo como `https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/1234/username`).

Particularmente, quando vou buscar minhas respostas, não costumo usar `is:answer`, mas isso é porque eu tenho muito mais respostas que perguntas e os resultados acabam tendo somente respostas na maioria dos casos. Mas se você tem muitas perguntas, pode ser interessante filtrar mais a busca.

#### Ops...

[Nos comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8345/por-que-n%C3%A3o-criar-uma-barra-de-pesquisa-para-respostas-dadas-pelo-usu%C3%A1rio#comment32988_8345) eu sugeri usar `is:answer` juntamente com `title:título da pergunta`, mas testando melhor descobri que o `title` acaba forçando a busca em perguntas, mesmo que o operador `is:answer` esteja presente. Por exemplo, [em uma busca por `user:157404 is:answer title:Como criar uma variável`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157404%20is%3Aanswer%20title%3AComo%20criar%20uma%20vari%C3%A1vel), os resultados dizem:

> *Search options: title como, **questions only**, user 157404*

Confesso que não tinha usado muito esta combinação (eu geralmente busco apenas por palavras no corpo da resposta, e não pelo título da pergunta, e como já disse, não costumo usar `is:answer`), então peço desculpas pelo conselho errado.

Então nesse caso específico, bastaria buscar por [`user:157404 Como criar uma variável`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157404%20Como%20criar%20uma%20vari%C3%A1vel) ou [`user:157404 is:answer Como criar uma variável`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157404%20is%3Aanswer%20Como%20criar%20uma%20vari%C3%A1vel), ou ainda [`user:157404 is:answer body:Como criar uma variável`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157404%20is%3Aanswer%20body%3AComo%20criar%20uma%20vari%C3%A1vel).

---

#### "Mas eu não sei fazer busca avançada, quero outra barra de busca só para isso"

Sobre o [seu comentário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8345/por-que-n%C3%A3o-criar-uma-barra-de-pesquisa-para-respostas-dadas-pelo-usu%C3%A1rio#comment32992_8345): *podem existir pessoas que não conheçam essa forma de filtragem*.

Quando você clica na barra de busca, aparece o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, ela já mostra algumas opções, além de um link "Ajuda com pesquisa", que direciona para [esta página da Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/searching). Lá são explicadas todas as opções existentes.

Não acho que valha a pena criar **outra** barra de pesquisa só para um caso específico.

Imagine se a cada vez que alguém pensar em um caso específico de busca, fosse sugerido criar outra barra de pesquisa dedicada àquela busca. Mesmo que seja "muito usado", vai faltar espaço na tela para tanta barra.

A busca avançada já supre essa e todas as outras necessidades. Tudo bem que a busca em si poderia ser melhorada (**é mais fácil procurar no Google**, suas chances de encontrar algo são bem maiores do que usando a busca do site), mas aí já é outra história...

Quanto ao fato de "alguém não conhecer", aí já entramos em outro assunto: o fato de que a maioria dos usuários não quer aprender como o site funciona (não estou falando especificamente de você, pois ao perguntar algo no Meta, já demonstra um interesse no funcionamento do site superior ao da maioria).

Algumas coisas no funcionamento do site não são óbvias e nem fáceis de aprender? Não são. [A interface poderia ajudar mais os usuários](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803)? Com certeza. A página de busca avançada poderia [ter vários *checkboxes* e/ou campos de texto](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) com essas opções, em vez de fazer a gente digitar manualmente operadores específicos? Poderia.

Mas o fato é que essas opções que você está sugerindo já existem. Não precisa criar outra barra de pesquisa só para um caso específico. Se as pessoas não querem aprender a usar o site, o problema é a falta de interesse delas (*engraçado que para aprender a usar recursos "escondidos"/obscuros de redes sociais e aplicativos inúteis, "todo mundo" tem disposição, mas divago*).

---

#### Se pensar bem, "já existe" algo parecido

Talvez não da forma que você quer, mas se você for no [seu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/current), verá que a barra de busca já estará preenchida com `user:seu-id-de-usuário`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aí é só clicar lá e digitar o restante dos termos da busca. Não é algo tão direto quanto você sugeriu, mas de certa forma "já existe" o recurso, ou pelo menos parte dele (o mesmo vale para qualquer perfil de usuário, o ID já estará preenchido no campo de busca, "facilitando" um pouco a vida de quem for fazer a busca por *posts* daquele usuário).

---

## Busca por perguntas duplicadas

Aí vale o que foi mencionado [nos comentários](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8345/por-que-n%C3%A3o-criar-uma-barra-de-pesquisa-para-respostas-dadas-pelo-usu%C3%A1rio#comment32990_8345): se quer procurar por uma duplicada, faça a busca em todo o site (ou no Google, que como já disse, tem mais chances de encontrar algo).

Tudo bem que às vezes eu também indico as minhas respostas como duplicadas, porque eu lembro de já ter respondido sobre o assunto, mas na maioria das vezes que indico duplicadas, são de perguntas que eu não respondi. E na verdade o que importa mesmo é procurar a duplicada que melhor responde (a que tiver as melhores respostas), independente de quem respondeu.

Se for um assunto, como no seu exemplo, que vai ter "muitos resultados", aí com certeza a pergunta é duplicada mesmo, pois já foi feita várias e várias vezes (com tem acontecido ultimamente com [certos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=hojesejoga) [sites](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=imprimirAzul4) de "[exercícios online](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=digital%20house)"). Nesse caso, não tem porque restringir as buscas à respostas de um único usuário (como já dito, busque pelas melhores respostas, independente do autor), não precisa ser necessariamente a sua (*no caso específico desses sites de exercícios, estou indicando a própria busca do site mesmo* - e aqui a gente cai no caso das pessoas não quererem aprender como o site funciona e só querer que os outros resolvam o problema delas - lembrando que a **primeira** recomendação de [Como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) é **Procurar** e pesquisar, o que quase ninguém tem feito ultimamente).

Comment: Concordo em tudo, só preciso esclarecer uma parte: Não é nem a questão de linkar respostas de outras pessoas, mas de buscar a resposta mais adequada para contextualizar/justificar a duplicata. Meu intuito no comentário foi justamente esse, existem ótimas respostas, além das nossas proprias, as vezes tão boas que cobrem muitos assuntos e perguntas e apesar de não sermos um "wiki da vida" o trabalho aqui feito deveria ser valorizado no sentido de "reaproveitar". No SOen inclusive tem alguns com mania de responderem perguntas com links de outras perguntas do SOen, o que não é proveitoso.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo com vc, editei a resposta para deixar mais claro esse ponto